# Java formatter in Eclipse - change java.lang.Object references to Object, add import statement as necessary

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, rad

I have a lot of generated code (classes from a WSDL) that I would like to clean up.  There are references like `java.lang.Object` and `the.very.same.namespace.as.TheGeneratedClass` all over.  Is there some automatic way I could convert these to just the class name `Object`, and import the class if necessary?  I'm using Rational Application Developer, so some kind of Save Action for Eclipse or RAD would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project(s) and choose Source > Organize Imports from the pop-up menu. You can also create a Save Action in the project Properties that will do it automatically from now on.